# converting a Object (containing string and integers) Pandas dataframe to a scipy sparse matrix

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a dataframe with two columns, one column is medicine name of dtype object it contains medicine name and few of the medicine name followed by its mg(eg. Avil25 and other row for Avil50) and other column is Price of dtype int . I'm trying to convert medicine name column into a scipy csr_matrix using the following lines of code:

`from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix`

`sparse_matrix = csr_matrix(medName)`

I am getting the following error message:

> `TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('O'),)`

as an alternative way I tried to remove the integers using(`medName.str.replace('\d+', '')`) from dataframe and tried `sparse_matrix = csr_matrix(medName.astype(str)`) . Still i am getting the same error.

> What's going on wrong here?
> What is another way to convert this dataframe to csr matrix?

Comment: The `dtype` (data) for a `csr` matrix has to be numeric - floats, integers.  `pandas` stores strings as object dtype; neither `object` nor a numpy string dtype can be used in sparse.

Answer (score 0):

you will have the encode strings to numeric data types for it to be made sparse. One solution ( probably not the most memory efficient) is to make a networkx graph, where the string-words will be the nodes, using the nodelist of the graph you can keep track of the word to numeric mapping.

Comment: I am trying to follow this documentation to merge data frames with similar names https://bergvca.github.io/2017/10/14/super-fast-string-matching.html I am having confusion that in the following script def get_matches_df(sparse_matrix, name_vector, top=100):  here what does the sparse matrix means! please refer the documentation for full script